# How can I use external resources in my api-platform app

Tags: php, rest, api-platform.com

I have application that implements api-platform.
This application has entity called UserSnapshot.

```php
namespace App\Entity;

/**
 * Class UserSnapshot
 * @package App\Entity
 */
class UserSnapshot
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * Position of user. Information only.
     * @var Position
     */
    protected $position;
```

My Position entity is in different micro service. I can reach it using below URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8002/api/positions
```

This micro service is using api-platform to serve data;
Now I would like to use this external resource in my local app. How can I implement this to my UserSnapshot endpoint?

How can I create Position endpoint in my application?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement [a custom DataProvider](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/data-providers/#custom-collection-data-provider) to forward the request to the remote micro-service.

In this data provider, you'll probably want to execute the HTTP query using Guzzle, the deserialize the JSON data in your local entity, and let API Platform serialize it again.

If you want to return the retrieved JSON as is and don't need to decode then reencode the JSON-LD, you may use a [custom action instead](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations/#creating-custom-operations-and-controllers) and skip the deserialization/re-serialization part.

Comment: I have doubts about this approach. When I use custom data provider I have to deserialize whole response and serialize it again although there is no important changes in that process. If I use controller custom action I don't know how to deal with filters for this resource.

Comment: Filtering is done in the microservice or in the main app?

Comment: Another question: is the microservice available publicly or not?

Comment: So it's not a problem to use a custom controller, forward the URL path + the query parameters to the microservice, you'll get the data already filtered, and you'll be able to output it as is.

Comment: Well it is a problem because I have to manually create query parameters In both sides of api. On the other hand my result will not have correct information where this results are from.
 `"@context": "/api/contexts/Position"`

Comment: > Well it is a problem because I have to manually create query parameters In both sides of api.

Maybe can you share your resource class in a vendor?

Comment: I can share entity in vendor. Does it helps?